# Spring boot on docker not able to read a property file from resources, but the can without Docker with java -jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle, build.gradle

My Spring boot application has a property file with AWS credentials, when I run gradle bootJar , the fat jar with all dependencies is built and I can run it with java -jar

But when I bundle I build a Docker image, what I get is the following error, basically complaining that it can't find AWS credentials in the property file under resources

```
2021-03-23 17:51:01.542 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: To use assume role profiles the aws-java-sdk-sts module must be on the class path., com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@61a02480: profile file cannot be null, com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@23b9c9f8: Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]] with root cause
```

Note again that the I can run the assembled fat jar with java -jar that has the same credentials property file with no issues.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.myapp.myapp"]
```

And these are the docker tasks in build.gradle (after of course importing palantir) to build the image

```
apply plugin: 'com.palantir.docker'

group = 'com.myapp'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'mayapp'
    version =  '0.1.0'

}
task unpack(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn bootJar
    from(zipTree(tasks.bootJar.outputs.files.singleFile))
    into("build/dependency")
}
docker {
    name "${project.group}/${bootJar.baseName}"
    copySpec.from(tasks.unpack.outputs).into("dependency")
    buildArgs(['DEPENDENCY': "dependency"])
}
```

and this is how I run the container

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 com.myapp/myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be `ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","/app:/app/lib/*","com.myapp.myapp"]`
Not sure how your classpath was found with `app:app/lib/*`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I went ahead and made the change and rebuilt the docker image, I still get the same error. Do you see any other issues in the configs above.

Comment: Can you run `docker exec xxx ls /app`

Comment: AwsCredentials.properties
META-INF
application.properties
com
lib
static
templates

Comment: And then I ran `cat AwsCredentials.properties` and it has the right credentials

Comment: How do you load the properties file?

Comment: The AWS SDK does it, here's what I see  `// Make sure the path is absolute`
            `this.credentialsFilePath = "/" + credentialsFilePath;` then uses `InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(credentialsFilePath);`   which loads it into account properties `accountProperties.load(inputStream);`